# Merge txt file: TXTcollector

Tags: merge

I am looking for an easy way (without windows commands) to merge several txt files. 
Does anyone has an advice about the software TXTCollector? Is it a good one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A command prompt or .BAT/.CMD file can accomplish this easily by redirecting the output to a file.

```
type first.txt > merge.txt
type second.txt >> merge.txt
type third.txt >> merge.txt
```

A single redirection operator (e.g. `>`) will *always* create a new file with the output, overwriting any existing target file. Double redirection operators (e.g. `>>`) will *append* the output to an existing file or create a new file if one does not exist.

In the above .CMD script, the contents of *first.txt, second.txt* and *third.txt* will be in the new *merge.txt*.

**EDIT** Sample .CMD files

In its simplest form, a .CMD script that loops through the .txt files in a folder would look something like this.

```
@echo OFF
FOR %%c in (*.txt) DO TYPE %%c >> merge.txt
```

There is plenty of examples available on the web if you need to make adjustments for your particular situation.

Comment: I will check this. The point is that I don´t want to write the name of all of the files... ;) thanks!

Comment: A .CMD can cycle through all of the file in a folder (optionally filtered with a filemask like *.txt).

Comment: I don´t see what you mean here Jeeped... sorry

Comment: I really don´t know anything with CMD. Thanks but I will wait advice about TXTCollector ;)